# Search Site on Google Exclude a Folder

Tags: google-search

I'm familiar with searching a specific website on Google.

```
site:yahoo.com
```

I'm in a situation where I need to exclude a certain folder. Which I would have expected to be as follows.

```
site:yahoo.com -site:yahoo.com/sports/
```

Is this possible? If so how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can AND searches.

I just tested
`test site:yahoo.com AND -site:yahoo.com/sports/`
which returned something from sports.yahoo.com in with the rest,
so I tried
`test site:yahoo.com AND -site:yahoo.com/sports/ AND -site:sports.yahoo.com`

which looked good

Comment: I'm pretty sure AND is the default, so `test site:yahoo.com -site:yahoo.com/sports/ -site:sports.yahoo.com` should have the same results.